# What sort of relative clauses can follow "who knows" (as a rhetorical question) when it's not used as a separate sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses, rhetorical-questions

I think I've seen someone used "who knows" not in a separate sentence. Let me first explain what I'm **not** looking for:

> Someday our little Donald might become our president. Who knows?

This is a typical example I find in those "English for learners" websites.  Here "who knows" is used in a separate sentence. ***But*** I wonder if there are ways to use it in a part of a single sentence, such as "Who knows *somebody* does *something*."  And if that is allowed, what sort of relative clauses can follow "who knows"?

If such usages are common, it would be great if you could point me to a few examples online.  I've found this but not many others:

> [It's never an easy decision: Should I interview someone who wants to talk in public, but who knows that a word out of line could mean arrest and imprisonment?](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-33513976)

Incidentally, does the BBC writer imply a word can *likely* to lead to arrest and imprisonment here?

Comment: Idiomatically we just don't use ***Who knows?*** the way you're thinking. Your final example is almost certainly from a non-native speaker, because the normal form there would be, for example, *... but **who would have thought** that a word out of line could mean arrest and imprisonment?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the context of the question throws off your reading of the final example (it did for me at first as well). I believe the sentence is talking about someone who wants to talk, but knows it isn't a good idea. But reading "who knows?" with the inflection of a question so many times before reading the example makes you read "who" as a question instead of a relative pronoun.

Comment: @Sarah: I didn't spend a lot of time thinking about what that final example might be *intended* to mean. It simply didn't look like anything a native speaker would say, given the earlier stuff about *Who knows?* On looking again I see it's normal English, but nothing to do with OP's title or rhetorical questions. Whatever - I'll leave the comment there, otherwise yours wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers exactly my point. The whole question primes you to read it as a rhetorical question (which doesn't seem natural/make much sense), but stepping back and reading it neutrally it is perfectly natural, just not as a rhetorical question.

Comment: @Sarah: I didn't notice until *after* my second comment that you'd actually explained things in an Answer (since upvoted). But clearly we were both *susceptible* to the misreading because of the way the question is framed (even though only you took the trouble to think it through), so it may actually be an advantage for OP or others to see how easy it is to be misled if you just consider two consecutive words *in isolation*, without regard to their syntactic role in the complete utterance.

Comment: I think Sarah is right about the BBC sentence, but I believe that it's not a very well-written one.  We're "primed" to think of "who knows" in the "who knows?" sense by the OP's question, but the BBC sentence would be clearer if it read "...someone who wants to talk in public but knows that..."  The "who" and the comma actually make things less clear here, because we can imagine a sentence like "Before I make my decision, I want to talk to someone with personal experience, but who knows whether that would actually discourage me?" in which "who knows" *does* have the questioning sense.

Answer (score 4):

Your BBC sentence is using "who knows" in a totally different way than the premise of your question.

In "Someday our little Donald might become our president. Who knows?", the "who knows?" part is like saying "nobody can know".

You could use this same meaning of the phrase in a sentence like "Who knows what will happen next year?". It is a rhetorical question, which does not expect an answer.

It could also be the start of a non-rhetorical question. For example, a teacher may ask a class "Who knows when the Civil War started?". She is expecting students who know to raise their hand.

In your example "who" in "who knows" is a relative pronoun referring to the person referenced earlier, just like a few words earlier when it says "who wants".

The sentence could be rephrased "Should I interview a person that wants to talk in public, even though that person knows that a word out of line could mean arrest and imprisonment?". The meaning boils down to "If this person talks to me, they could easily say something that would lead to their own imprisonment."

Comment: Ahh you're right...

Comment: +1.    ... someone who wants X .... but who knows Y ...